# Text Not centering in Multirow table

Tags: multicolumn, multirow

I am not able to center text in a multirow table, I want all column values to be centered
here is the code

```
\begin{table}[]
        \caption{$\alpha$ values obtained Analytically}
    \label{table:Alphavalues}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        OCL                   & Report  (r)     & Selection  & Output \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{99\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{20} & 20\%     & 0.55                  \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                     & 40\%     & 0.82                  \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{99\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{30} & 20\%     & 0.77                  \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                     & 40\%     & 0.76                  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Well `l` stands for left-aligned columns. If you want centred columns then you should use the `c` specifier.

Comment: What's wrong with [this answer to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584570/134144)? There, the columns of a similar looking table are all horizontally centered, since `c` type columns (instead of `l`, like in your example) were used.

Comment: You have three questions with not accepted answers. Please consider to change that.

Comment: It is requested to accept the answer if it met the requirement -- if not please spell out the shortcomings -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584483/uniform-size-for-tikzi-state-diagram

Comment: @jsbibra: How is the question you linked to related to this question about centered text in a table?

Comment: @leandriis It's not related. It's about a non-accepted answer of the same OP.